# facebook shares count not accurate

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api

may i know why this three urls return difference of count?

https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http://www.rotikaya.com/iqram-dinzly-tinggalkan-jalan-jalan-cari-makan-kerana-takut-gemuk/&layout=standard&show_faces=false&width=300&action=like&colorscheme=light&height=30

https://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://www.rotikaya.com/iqram-dinzly-tinggalkan-jalan-jalan-cari-makan-kerana-takut-gemuk/

http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=links.getStats&format=json&urls=http://www.rotikaya.com/iqram-dinzly-tinggalkan-jalan-jalan-cari-makan-kerana-takut-gemuk/
 (deprecated but more accurate)

Comment: possibly because the Facebook DB is *Eventually* consistent... not automatically consistent. It takes time for stuff to propagate through their data centers

Comment: see new links, totally different

Answer (score 0):

The Graph link is intended to reflect the number a like button would show, which is an combination of several metrics.

The getStats endpoint does a more detailed breakdown. If you look at the total value on it, you'll see they match up.

Answer (score 0):

> https://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/

This displays total of likes and the deprecated shares as a whole

> http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=links.getStats&format=json&urls=http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/

This one displays all the data, as you can see if you add the like count and share count it is just the same with the previous URL

Comment: https://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://www.rotikaya.com/iqram-dinzly-tinggalkan-jalan-jalan-cari-makan-kerana-takut-gemuk/

http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=links.getStats&format=json&urls=http://www.rotikaya.com/iqram-dinzly-tinggalkan-jalan-jalan-cari-makan-kerana-takut-gemuk/

where is the likes count

Comment: in the first link I guess there is just one like(try sharing it if it increases) in the second link it is "like_count":21

Comment: if you want to see just the like and share you could use this
https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT%20share_count,click_count,%20like_count,%20total_count%20FROM%20link_stat%20WHERE%20url=”Place your url here”